# not able to open a file in write mode in cpp, strerro says permission denied

Tags: c++

I am trying to do a simple file operation by opening it and writing something.
Here is the code:

```
// image_read.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

#include<cerrno>
#include<cstring>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("C:/file_example.txt");
    cout << myfile.is_open();
    if (!(myfile.is_open()))
    {
        cout << "cannot open the file, error number" << strerror(errno);
    }
    myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    myfile.close();
    
    return 0;
}
```

getting the error from `cout<<strerror` as **permission denied**

How can I resolve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you replace `ofstream demosiac_out;` and the following `demosiac_out.open(...);` line with `ostream& demosiac_out = std::cout;`? Does it print the pixel values to screen?

Comment: what does "not able" mean? What happens? Do you get an error? No error, but nothing is written to the file?

Comment: @idclev463035818, I am not able to open the file, I get the print statement displayed from if(!demosiac-out)

Comment: you mean `cout << "cannot open the file";` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 yes

Comment: don't get me wrong, but "not able" and "does not work" do not really explain the issue, in the question you should decribe what the code is supposed to do and what it does instead, the latter is missing

Comment: Instead of printing that line, print the actual error. `cout << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';` It may provide some more info, like "permission denined" something like that. Include both `<cstring>` and `<errno>` to get that to work.

Comment: @TedLyngmo  #include<errno> is not working its saying cannot open file/directory
Is the spelling of errno correct?

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `<cerrno>`

Comment: @idclev463035818 apologies for that, I have changed the description accordingly,

Comment: So, what did the `cout << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';` line print?

Comment: apologies for not replying quickly, i was trying to print the "errno" with a simple code, its giving me an error. I will update the code I am trying to implement in a minute

Comment: @TedLyngmo it is saying permission is denied

Comment: @maheshmutyala Ok, then it's easy. Do you have permissions to write into the directory where you try to save the file? Is the permissions on the file itself set so you can't overwrite it? You are usually _not_ permitted to create files in the `C:/` directory on windows unless you are logged in as Administrator or run an elevated process.

Comment: @TedLyngmo 

Thanks for the suggestionI tried running visual studio as an administrator and executed the mentioned code, it worked, but if I change the path by changing the line 
myfile.open("C:/Users/20181217/Desktop/images/imgs/demosiac_gold.txt");, it is again saying permission is denied
How should I go about this?

Comment: Is `20181217` your username? Does the directory `C:/Users/20181217/Desktop/images/imgs` exist? Does the file `demosiac_gold.txt` exist in that directory? Do you have permissions to remove that file?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, yes 20181217 is my username, yes demosiac_gold.txt exists in the directory. Even if it is not present in the directory, it will create one write?
when I used the path C:/file_example.txt, example.txt was not present at that time, so it created the file.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it is working till the path c:/users/20181217/
The file is getting created, but if try to save in c:/Users/20181217/Desktop, it is saying permission is denied.
it is not accepting any other path after 20181217

Comment: So, you can create a program that reads the file, like `std::ifstream is("C:/Users/20181217/Desktop/images/imgs/demosiac_gold.txt"); if(is) std::cout << "success\n";`? Perhaps `Desktop` is a junction of some sort and it's not actually your directory (just an idea). Can you create files in `Desktop` manually, with `notepad.exe` for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Please try to set 'UAC Execution Level'  = 'requireAdministrator'.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/manifestuac-embeds-uac-information-in-manifest